# File cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system with pubxml

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy

I've a really particular situation. I'm using a script to execute post deploy action.
I've inside my .pubml the following snippet of code

```
<Target Name="CopyServiceModules"  AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish">
<Exec Command="powershell.exe -file &quot;$(SolutionDir)PowerShellScripts\CopyModulesFiles.ps1&quot; -workspacePath &quot;$(ProjectDir)Modules&quot; -deployPath &quot;$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\Modules&quot;" />
```

If I run the script from powershell it works, when it's executed by visual studio I got this error

```
file cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system with pubxml file
```

I've just run

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

on my machine but it doesn't work.
I also have run Visual Studio 2015 with administrator priviledges

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the -ExecutionPolicy to your Exec line:

```
<Exec Command="powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file &quot;$(SolutionDir)PowerShellScripts...
```

Comment: Thanks! now I've got one last problem but I open another thread